# Python. finding a word within a scrambled string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not looking for a code, I'm looking for some advice on how to write this code.
I need to be able to find a word the user enters within a second input of random characters. I need to figure out if the word they have inputted can be created with the characters of the second input

```
input1: dog

input2: drkeloreqkg

output: True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since order is not important, you can just use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
set(input1).issubset(input2)
# True
```

In the case you wouldn't expect for instance `ap` to be able to *create* `appp`, you could build a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from both strings and subtract their respective counts, and *then* check if `string1` is a subset of the resulting `keys`:

```
from collections import Counter
input1='appppp' 
input2='ap' 

set(input1).issubset((Counter(input1)-Counter(input2)).keys())
# False
```

Comment: The question did not specify if character count is important, 'ap' shouldn't be able to produce 'appppp' if character count is a factor.

Comment: The question did not really specify much at all, right? @MichaelHsi

Comment: True. I'm just throwing out some concern with the question's wording

Comment: Updated @MichaelHsi , you did raise a good point. We could use Counters to contamplate such case

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. all characters in the first input should be within the second input to be prompt with True.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the character count does not matter as you mentioned in your comments, you can just loop over the word and check that the characters belong in a set of the other input:

```
def check_words(input1, input2):
    s = set(input2)

    for letter in input1:
        if letter not in s:
            return False
    return True


print(check_words('dog', 'drkeloreqkg')) # True
```